# Communication between Windows service and applications in different user sessions

Tags: windows-services, named-pipes

I have the following situation:

Windows Server environment with multiple user sessions.

Windows Service is listening on well known port.

Tray application in each user session which is started automatically.

Silverlight (SL) application is running in browser and communicating with Windows Service using sockets and predefined port.

My goal is the following: user interacts with SL application, SL application communicates to Windows service using sockets and afterward Windows service should communicate to proper tray application which located in the same user session like browser that initiate call.

Communication between Windows service and tray applications is planed to be done using named pipes.

Question: how to define/transfer names of named pipes to Windows service to establish right (windows service -> tray app in correct user session) connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't find exact solution for described problem. But it is possible to use custom protocol concept.

SL application generates custom protocol links and registered application handles such links in user session. Afterwards such application can establish two-way communication with Windows Service that is listening on well-known port.